# Create a kml for a Google Earth tree view item through vb-net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, google-earth

I try to write kmls for Google Earth tree view items, getting their items properties through visual studio.
With the following code I get all Google Earth tree view items.

```
Imports EARTHLib.ApplicationGEClass
Public _ge As New EARTHLib.ApplicationGE
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim TreeArray() As Object
        For Each item In _ge.GetMyPlaces.GetChildren()
            ReDim Preserve TreeArray(i)
            TreeArray(i) = _ge.GetMyPlaces.GetChildren(i + 1)
            i +=  items1 
        Next
```

But the available taken _ge properies are only names and time intervals.
Any idea on how to continue ?